# How to set text color for MaterialButton from code?

Tags: android, material-components, material-components-android

I am using MaterialButton with outline style and can't set text color from code. Is there setTextColor method? I can change it via android:textColor from XML, but not from code.

Using `com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0-rc01`

Comment: you can use text.setTextColor(Color.RED);

Comment: @NagendraHariKarthick solution will work but if you don't have to change this color stick to colors provided by your theme configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was bug in 1.0.0-rc01 version and it was fixed in release version.